# how can i change the colors in apex bar chat

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, material-ui, apexcharts

I'm building a bar chart in **react** and **mui** using apex-chart,
i want to change the bar colors,
is there any solution for this??? i've tried many things but i think there is no way to achieve this thing.
currently i have this color combination

[image]

but i want to achieve this

[image]

Here is my code,

```
        chart: {
            parentHeightOffset: 0,
            toolbar: { show: false },
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                borderRadius: 4,
                distributed: true,
                columnWidth: '20%',
                endingShape: 'rounded',
                startingShape: 'rounded',
            },
        },
        stroke: {
            width: 2,
            colors: [theme.palette.background.paper],
        },
        // legend: { show: false },
        grid: {
            strokeDashArray: 7,
            padding: {
                top: -1,
                right: 0,
                left: -12,
                bottom: 5,
            },
        },
        dataLabels: { enabled: false },

        states: {
            hover: {
                filter: { type: 'none' },
            },
            active: {
                filter: { type: 'none' },
            },
        },
        xaxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Nov',
                'Dec',
            ],
            tickPlacement: 'on',
            labels: { show: true },
            axisTicks: { show: false },
            axisBorder: { show: false },
        },
        yaxis: {
            show: true,
            tickAmount: 4,
            labels: {
                offsetX: -17,
                formatter: (value) =>
                    `${value > 999 ? `${(value / 1000).toFixed(0)}` : value}k`,
            },
        },
    };



<ReactApexcharts
                    type='bar'
                    height={205}
                    options={options}
                    series={[
                        {
                            name: 'Income',
                            data: [37, 57, 45, 75, 57, 40, 65],
                            color:theme.palette.primary.main
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'Expenses',
                            data: [32, 82, 23, 69, 90, 14, 60],
                            color: theme.palette.success.main,
                        },
                    ]}
                />
```

I'm passing colors but it didn't work, for income bars i want orange color but for expenses colors i want green color

Answer (score 0):

You should remove [`plotOptions.bar.distributed`](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/plotoptions/bar/#distributed) (which is `false` by default) and use this [array of colors](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/colors/) to colorize your series.

Take a look at this simple example, which is essentially your code without React:

```js
let options = {
  series: [{
    name: 'Income',
    data: [37, 57, 45, 75, 57, 40, 65]
  }, {
    name: 'Expenses',
    data: [32, 82, 23, 69, 90, 14, 60]
  }],
  chart: {
    type: 'bar',
    height: 205,
    parentHeightOffset: 0,
    toolbar: { show: false }
  },
  colors: ['#ff7c1b', '#38cb89'], // <--- HERE
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      borderRadius: 4,
      columnWidth: '20%',
      endingShape: 'rounded',
      startingShape: 'rounded'
    }
  },
  grid: {
    strokeDashArray: 7,
    padding: {
      top: -1,
      right: 0,
      left: -12,
      bottom: 5
    }
  },
  dataLabels: { enabled: false },
  states: {
    hover: {
      filter: { type: 'none' }
    },
    active: {
      filter: { type: 'none' }
    }
  },
  xaxis: {
    categories: [
      'Jan',
      'Feb',
      'Mar',
      'Apr',
      'May',
      'Jun',
      'Jul',
      'Aug',
      'Sep',
      'Nov',
      'Dec'
    ],
    tickPlacement: 'on',
    labels: { show: true },
    axisTicks: { show: false },
    axisBorder: { show: false }
  },
  yaxis: {
    show: true,
    tickAmount: 4,
    labels: {
      offsetX: -17,
      formatter: (value) =>
      `${value > 999 ? `${(value / 1000).toFixed(0)}` : value}k`
    }
  }
};

let chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector('#chart'), options);
chart.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>

<div id="chart"></div>
```